# How to Clear the cache token in MSAL SPA?

Tags: javascript, azure, active-directory, single-page-application, msal.js

I have the functionality when the user doesn't accept the Permission ( At the first time login) I am redirecting it to Signin page. Since the token is cached it is constantly showing the Permission page.

Is there a way to clear the token which is cached ?

Comment: I don't think that's MSAL that is caching there, it's Azure AD. You can specify a `prompt` query parameter to the request to change what Azure AD does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request (scroll down to the table and find the prompt parameter for the options)

Comment: Cool. It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that's MSAL that is caching there, it's Azure AD. You can specify a prompt query parameter to the request to change what Azure AD does: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow#send-the-sign-in-request (scroll down to the table and find the prompt parameter for the options).

For example `prompt=select_account` will force an account chooser.

Comment: Hello juunas, will the select prompt work on mobile?